# Reading big files from an SSD in Windows is slower than expected

Tags: windows, ssd, performance

I've been having reading problems with my SSD Samsung 840 Evo 250GB on Windows 10

The problem is, very strangely, very slow read speeds for some files, not all of then... particularly and more noticeable in big files.

Testing on CrystalDiskMark the values appears to be ok, 530MB/s Read and 500MB/s Write Speed.

#### Here is when things starts to get weird:

If I duplicate the same file in the same drive, when I read the copy, the speeds appears to return to normal, but the original file still reads very slow...

I made the following test:

Calculate the file MD5 sum in PowerShell (to force a file read).

In the original the read speed is about **21MB/s** then when I duplicate the file the read speed rose to **375MB/s** (which is normal for this drive)

And I did verify if I have **trim** and **ACHI** enable.

Someone has any clue to what may be happening here? Bad SSD? Driver issue? Windows issue?

Reading original file:

[image: Reading original file.]

Reading copy of original file:

[image: Reading copy of original file.]

Here is the SMART Readings of the mentioned Drive:

[image]

Just to translate it has 12086 hours powered on.

Comment: When you make a copy of the file, it is cached in memory.  So the access is faster.  This in itself does not prove anything.  It is possible that your drive is starting to fail and is having to do retries.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide SMART diagnostics

Comment: @RohitGupta I restarted the system between tests, to discard any chance of ram cache. The same behavior remains.

Comment: @DavidPostill I attached the smart info, it does report 90% healthy level...

Comment: Have you used [Samsung Magician](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/) to check that the firmware on the drive is up to date? (It should be at least EXT0DB6Q.)

Comment: ... the problem was first reported back in 2014: [Samsung’s 840 EVO update fixes slow reads with old data](https://techreport.com/review/27212/samsungs-840-evo-update-fixes-slow-reads-with-old-data/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton That was a really helpful suggestion! I haven't tried Samsung Magician yet, but I just installed and it reported that I am already in the latest available version... It did suggest to update my NVMe 970 Evo Plus firmware... but it's unrelated. 
The article you shared seens to talk exactly about my problem! Since the file I'm using to test is indeed an old file, and the "new" copy of it reads ok. I will try to find the software they mention "Performance Restoration" and run.

Comment: @AndréHenrique The image in the question shows a firmware version of EXT0BB6Q, but the latest available is EXT0DB6Q, according to a [Samsung Downloads Page](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/). You might need to get Magician to check again, or maybe do a reboot.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Weirdly the Samsung Magician was always showing EXT0BB6Q as the latest version...   But anyway, thanks to the article you shared I was able to find online the Samsung 840 EVO Performance Restoration Tool 1.1. And ran it. It took about 2 hours. And it actually updated the firmware to version EXT0CB6Q, and after some tests I stated that the performance was indeed restored!! I'm very happy! I though my SSD was done for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @AndrewMorton, I was able to actually find the cause of my problem, it was related to the topic discussed in this article: https://techreport.com/review/27212/samsungs-840-evo-update-fixes-slow-reads-with-old-data/

In the end the problem was not related to the size of the file, but it's age, It's a known issue for the Samsung 940 EVO, to perform badly while reading older files.

Turns out that I ended downloading the software **Samsung 840 EVO Performance Restoration Tool 1.1** which is available from the samsung support site: https://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/MZ-7TE250BW/

[image: Samsung performance restoration]

It ended up taking almost 2 hours to finish, but after that I could state that the performance really did change, the speeds are now as fast as a new file!